# Pulling outlets from the wall for backsplash install

Tags: receptacle

I’m having my countertops replaced and having my backsplash replaced with the same quartz as the counters, so my outlets will need to be extended for the thicker material.  The installer said I needed to pull the outlets from the box so they can install around them (basically just having them hang free from the box).  My question is, once I pull the faceplate and screws that attach it to the box, so I need to leave the power off until they are done?   Or can the power be turned back on.   My lighting and outlets are on some of the same breakers so they won’t have overhead light if I need to leave power off.  Obviously I’ll cut power to pull them free from the box, I’m just not sure Id it’s safe to restore power why they are not secured in the box.

Comment: With them out of the boxes, you have live power that people(you and workers) are not protected from.  A miss place hand or a slip and sparks will fly, into someone.

Comment: Power off. Warn them they'll need site lights because [for some unimaginable reason] your lighting is on the same circuit.

Comment: @Tetsujin Agreed, like the completely unimaginable and unrealistic situation of living in a house which was not freshly constructed.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - I'l choose to read that as not sarcastic, but where I live lighting is on 5-10A, sockets are on 30A & ne'er the twain shall meet.

Comment: @Tetsujin In general it's assumed that posts on this site are U.S.-based unless explicitly noted or revealed in the question details. My 1940's home has the entire upstairs on a single 15A circuit: 3 bed+1 bath worth of lights and outlets. Having the luxury of lights on a separate circuit is a fairly recent practice.

Comment: @Tetsujin The differences in design approaches are amusing.  Keep in mind America rolled out electrical very early in the game, and so was locked into standards early, such as ~100V bulbs (due to practicability) and split-phase (due to Edison's obsession with DC and flailing attempts to deal with voltage drop).  UK was still struggling with standards nto the 1920s, and so had the benefit of learning from everyone else's mistakes.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus In the 1940s, that *was* "lights on a separate circuit".  Sockets were only conceived of for plug-in lighting.  Nobody imagined we'd be using them to power everything under the sun.  Honestly if it hadn't snuck up on us, the US probably would have kept 120V for lights and 240V for small appliance branch circuits.  That is what NEMA 6-15 and 6-20 were made for.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: I've long thought that there should be a standard light-duty plug in the US for things under ~3 amps, and that splitting extension leads should have a 15A plug and be designed to accept either one 15A plug or multiple light-duty plugs.  The idea that a light-duty extension cord should perfectly happily accept two plug-in 1500W heaters seems a bit crazy, especially since the cord might have a 20A breaker that would take a long time to trip under such a load.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - agreed on the historical basis, but the UK had a major revamp in 1947 & introduced the then new standard 13A plug. Sure, it took decades to get rid of all the old structures once & for all, but that standard is still in use today - https://electrical.theiet.org/media/1688/the-origin-of-the-bs-1363-plug-and-socket-outlet-system.pdf The UK had a lot of rebuilding to do in the late 40s which the US never suffered, so the time was ripe for innovation.

Comment: Are you authorised to do electrical work in your location?  Or is the installer just pre-warning they will have to do this?

Answer (score 6):

The outlets need to be pulled away from the wall and ideally box extenders should be installed as well. If your boxes are plastic they make rings for this purpose. For metal boxes you can use mud rings of various thickness. While you are at it, might be a good time to replace the outlets with new ones, for example swapping the color or for decora style. While the power is off you can unhook the outlets and cap them with wire nuts so you can turn the power back on, then rewire them after the tiling is done

Comment: This is actually practical advice especially since the OP notes that the lights are on the same breaker as the outlets. However, it is important to take pictures of the wiring of _each_ outlet _before_ removing any single wire! We've had _far_ too many "help, I pulled the old fixture and now I don't know how to wire it back up" questions where someone didn't bother taking pics first. Of note, though, is that it's possible that the switches & lighting come _after_ outlets, so disconnecting them may disconnect the lights, too. Caution must be used if the outlets are to be removed.

Comment: Thanks for those additional comments, I thought I was going crazy when my answer had multiple downvotes. I didn't provide additional context for the wiring since there wasn't more detail in the original post but good points about what else may be involved.

Comment: Only one DV, but I'm not sure why. TBH, it would take more time, but I'd suggest 1) turn off breaker, 2) pull outlet, 3) take pics, 4) remove wiring, 5) cap _all_ wires, 6) turn on breaker, 7) make sure everything else works as expected. That way if the answer to 7) is "no", you know exactly where the problem is and can reconnect things.

Comment: I downvoted this because you'd better have some really, really good 3rd party liability insurance & a good lawyer if your fitter manages to fly backwards across the room because you left the power on.

Comment: @Tetsujin "unhook the outlets and **cap them with wire nuts** so you can turn the power back on," (emphasis added). If your wire nuts still allow power to flow to where someone can get bit, then you don't have good wire nuts and/or have done a very poor job of installing them.

Comment: How much water does this fit need? Adhesive? Grouting? Hole-cutting to fit round the sockets?

Comment: @Tetsujin fair, I should have included pushing the capped wires back into the box. If you are cutting back splash it should be done off the wall prior to install. Most tile installers don't even turn off the power and just let the plugs dangle.

Answer (score 6):

Leave the power off, or you risk having to explain the dead quartz countertop fitters.

If you just remove the faceplates, then you will be leaving bare live wires exposed in the back boxes.  Anyone could touch them without realizing that they are live.

Answer (score 2):

If you are pulling the outlets themselves out of the box any distance, then you should leave the power off (or at least off while work is being performed).  Most all outlets have side terminals/screws to connect the wiring . Once the outlets are pulled most any distance out of the box, those screws will be exposed.  Workers will have any number of metal tools, and perhaps cleaning agents (liquids) that you won't want them to come into contact with a hot wire.

Now if you are only removing faceplates, and not pulling outlets from their boxes, its a slightly different situation, but bear in mind, if tools are being used, you have an open path to those terminals.

Comment: Thank you both.   That was my assumption, but I wasn’t sure.  It just seemed intuitive that if I needed to cut power to perform the action that I would be necessary why it was displaced, but wanted to make sure.